# How can I write CSS with jQuery (or JS) to apply to current and future matches?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to dynamically set the height of an element `.selected` based on the screen height. `$('.selected').css('height', height);` and `$('.selected').height(height);` work but when another element becomes `.selected` it doesn't get affected by this rule.

What I really want to do is something like this:

```
var s = $('<style>.selected{height:'+height+'px}</style>').appendTo(document.head);
...
// change the height later
s.remove();
s = $('<style>.selected{height:'+new_height+'px}</style>').appendTo(document.head);
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: No, that's the best way to do it. Note that it would be better to modify your existing `style` tag rather than to add a new one to override an existing rule, if possible.

Comment: How about `s.text('.selected{height:'+new_height+'px}');` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `document.styleSheets[0].insertRule(".selected{height:"+new_height+"px}", 0);` or similar. [You can read more about manipulating stylesheets with insertRule here](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Stylesheet.insertRule)

In general tho, what you are doing is fine. If i was you i'd go with keeping a  refrence to your style element tho and replace it with the new one like this:

```
var s = $('<style>.selected{height:'+height+'px}</style>').appendTo(head);
...
// change the height later
s.replaceWith('<style>.selected{height:'+new_height+'px}</style>');
```

Comment: @drachenstern: the remove statement wasn't in the question when i wrote my answer ;) Otherwise, by some kind of magic, I managed to copy/paste a block of code missing a single line in the middle...

Comment: @drachenstern: I agree, it is an odd one, that I cannot explain by other means than magic copy/paste